# Ubuntu As a Router With IPSec VPN

Tags: networking, printing, vpn, firewall

I have a network setup with a nonconfigurable hardware firewall that connects a local subnet to my servers at a datacenter - we use Microsoft Remote Desktop Servers and have only stupid RD-clients in the local subnet.

I'd like to replace that firewall with an ubuntu machine for testing purposes und proof of concept.

The ubuntu machine connects via WLAN to the internet and shares the LAN port for the local subnet.
I managed to use WLAN, share the LAN port and assign the LAN port to the identical subnet as the hardware firewall did before (10.3.5.1/24).
I disconnected the hardware firewall.
Then I started VPN via Network-Manager and voila - the whole subnet (the LAN-port-side) was connected to my servers.
Every RD-client was able to establish a RDP-Session to a host in the datacenter.
So far, so well.

But connection to my printer in the local subnet from a printserver in the datacenter failed.

I think I "just" missed a point to "open" the local subnet for incoming traffic. I can ping  the printserver from any local client, but the other way round (a ping from the printserver to any local client) does not work.
Any ideas how to achive this?

QUICKSETUP:

RDP Servers & Print Server --> VPN Gateway 
<--INTERNET--> 
LTE MODEM --> WLAN --> UBUNTU ROUTER & FIREWALL & VPN Gateway --> LAN --> local subnet (client PC and printer)

Kind regards,
Fred

Comment: Too sad that nobody has an answer. However **I did** manage to setup the above mentioned scenario. Using my Liunx Laptop I share a VPN connection I receive from an otherwise "dumb" LTE router via WLAN to 20 users linked to my LAN.

Comment: Can you please share your solution as an answer.